# How to show that the Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind increases in m?

Tags: analysis, power-series, elliptic-integrals

How can you show that the complete elliptic integral of first kind 
$
\displaystyle K(m)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\mathrm du}{\sqrt{1-m^2\sin^2 u}}$
that is the same as a series 
$$K(m)=\frac{\pi}{2} \left(1+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}m^2 +\left(\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\right)^{2}m^4 +...+ \left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2n!!}  \right )^2m^{2n} + ... \right)$$

increases in m?

Thanks

Comment: The expansion of the integral you wrote has terms for every odd power of $m$ as well.

Comment: Im sorry, can you explain again? something wrong on the expansion?

Comment: Yes, something was definitely *wrong with the expansion*... But it seems you saw the problem since you made the necessary correction. Note that this makes the accepted answer, which addresses (incorrectly) the original version of your question, a little odd.

Comment: yeah yeah, thx, i already correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that the derivative with respect to $m$ is always positive:

Note that
$$K'(m)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{m \sin^2 u\, du}{(1-m^2\sin^2 u)^{3/2}} \geq 0$$
as the integrand is positive for all $0\leq m \leq 1$.

Comment: The numerator $m\sin u$ should read $\frac12\sin^2u$.