# Prove $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+t)^2-4t\sin^2{u}}}du \equiv \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2\sin^2{u}}}du$ for $0<t<1$.

Tags: definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

I am trying to prove that
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+t)^2-4t\sin^2{u}}}du \equiv \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2\sin^2{u}}}du\text{ for }0<t<1.$$

Context: In [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594297/in-a-circle-where-should-you-draw-a-line-segment-of-fixed-length-to-maximize-t/4595791#4595791), I am trying to make "Attempt $2$" work (after letting $x=2u)$. That is, I want to show that LHS here is increasing in $t$ for $0<t<1$. When playing with graphs, I accidentally discovered that LHS seems to be identical to RHS, which I know is [increasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253958/how-to-show-that-the-complete-elliptic-integral-of-the-first-kind-increases-in-m). But I do not know how to prove that LHS = RHS. Anyway, I think this question is interesting by itself.

Attempt: When $t=0$, we have LHS = RHS. Then I tried to show that $\frac{d}{dt}\text{LHS}=\frac{d}{dt}\text{RHS}$, but that seems to be even harder than the OP.

Comment: This is the famous Landen transformation given by $K((2\sqrt{t})/(1+t)) =(1+t)K(t)$ where $K(t) $ is integral on right side of your equation. A proof requires the substitution $\sin(2v-u)=t\sin u$ and involves reasonable amount of algebraic manipulation. See details at https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/pi-and-the-agm-evaluating-elliptic-integrals.html?m=0

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you, that answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\displaystyle  K(t) := \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2 \sin^2 u}} du$.
This is known as the Complete elliptic integral of the first kind.
Let $\displaystyle s := \sqrt{\frac{4t}{(1+t)^2}}$.
Then,
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+t)^2 -4t \sin^2 u}} du = \frac{1+\sqrt{1-s^2}}{2} K(s)$$
and
$$K(t) = K\left( \frac{2-s^2 + 2\sqrt{1-s^2}}{s^2}\right).$$

Hence it suffices to show that
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{1-s^2}}{2} K(s)  = K\left( \frac{2-s^2 + 2\sqrt{1-s^2}}{s^2}\right), \ 0 < s < 1. $$

This follows from a consideration of the characterization of $K$ by the arithmetic-geometric mean. See the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the characterization of $K$ by the arithmetic-geometric mean.